# Flutter watson assistant integration

Tags: flutter, ibm-watson

I created a **watson assistant** chatbot ,and a *flutter app* .I need to integrate flutter with Watson assistant .How i do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [watson_v2 package](https://pub.dev/packages/watson_assistant_v2) for you to integrate Watson Assistant into your flutter app by making API calls to version 2 of the service.

Here’s a [detailed blog post](https://medium.com/@lmellakyouness/build-a-chatbot-using-flutter-and-ibm-watson-assistant-75add52771fb) explaining how to achieve it step-by-step